# delete a button from a different function (python tkinter)

Tags: python, function, tkinter, button, global

I am writing a snake program which has a leaderboard built in. When someone clicks the leaderboard button, I would want my program to delete everything in the canvas (including the play_again and die buttons). Everything works except the buttons don't get deleted. Here is my code:

```
def game_over():
    label.config(text="Game Over! Score: {}".format(score))
    global play_again
    global die
    play_again=Button(canvas, text="Play Again", font=("consolas", 20), command=yes, bg="white", fg="black").place(anchor="center", relx=0.5, rely=0.46)
    die=Button(canvas, text="Quit", font=("consolas", 20), command=no, bg="white", fg="black").place(anchor="center", relx=0.5, rely=0.54)


def show_leaderboard():
    canvas.delete("all")
    play_again.forget()
    die.forget()
    leaderboard = Label(canvas, text="Leaderboard:", font=("consolas", 20), bg="black", fg="white")
    leaderboard.place(anchor="center", relx=0.5, rely=0.2)
```

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Then update your question with code to show us what you have tried so far. And use correct upper case letters please; e.g. in the title of your question.

Comment: Note that `play_again` and `die` are `None` because they are the result of `.place(...)`.  So you cannot *forget* them inside `show_leaderboard()` (actually you should get exception).

Comment: would you know a better way of doing it then?

Comment: You should separate `play_again = Button(...)` and `play_again.place(...)` onto two lines I believe.

Comment: Tried your tip David and it unforunatly didn't work for me. Any other suggestions on how it could work?